# Flask: How to remove cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I set cookies with the code suggested in the docs:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template(...))
    resp.set_cookie('username', 'the username')
    return resp
```

But how do I remove them? There is no remove_cookie method. I tried:

```
if request.cookies.get('sessionID');
    request.cookies.pop('sessionID', None)
```

but it turns out that the request.cookies object is immutable. What do I do?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's no HTTP header for deleting a cookie.  Traditionally you just set the cookie to a dummy value with an expiration date in the past, so it immediately expires.

```
resp.set_cookie('sessionID', '', expires=0)
```

This will set the session id cookie to an empty string that expires at unixtime `0`, which is almost certainly in the past.

Comment: Is this necessary, given ThiefMaster's answer?

Comment: a cookie can exist and still be empty.  using `expires` will actually delete it.  but the difference is pretty minor, yes.

Comment: Since flask session is stored on client side, is it possible for a poorly behaved client to  ignore this request and still keep the cookies?

Comment: @oeter well, sure; it's possible for a poorly behaved client to do _anything_.  that's what makes it poorly behaved  :)

Answer (score 26):

We can make us of delete_cookie() available from flask.Response.

```
resp.delete_cookie('username')
```

This will delete the cookie on response.
Here is [delete_cookie documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Response.delete_cookie.html).

Also you may want to have add **path** (default set to '/') and **domain** (default set to None).

```
resp.delete_cookie('username', path='/', domain='yourdomain.com')
```

Here is the interpreter screenshot which shows delete_cookie object in flask.Response.

[image: Python Interpreter Screenshot]

Comment: This does not delete the cookie on the developer tools > Application. Im not sure why. This is my snippet 

`res = make_response('', 204)
 res.delete_cookie(key='refresh_token', path='/') return res`

Comment: Check with passing domain as localhost. If the cookie is set with a domain, then it can be deleted with domain being passed.

Comment: I figured it out, `credentials: 'include'` should be set to headers on every request, this includes cookies on the request.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the cookie with an expiry that's in the past.

```
resp = make_response(render_template(...))
resp.set_cookie('username', expires=0)
return resp
```

By the way, I hope you don't actually expect that username cookie to be safe. Because it's not. The user can put anything he wants in there. The solution is usually to use the Flask session which uses a signed cookie that cannot be modified by the user.

Comment: Hm, okay. I know they aren't secure but I haven't gotten around to figuring out how to read signed cookies with a different service (I have Flask talking to a node.js app)