# Prevent Flask from ever sending Set-Cookie?

Tags: python, cookies, flask

Can I prevent [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework from ever sending a `Set-Cookie` header?

I'm using a variety of blueprints that use the session cookie. I'm wondering if there is a way to tell the framework to simply never try to set cookies. I'd like to not have to prepare each individual response using suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386304/flask-how-to-remove-cookies) or using `app.after_request`.

Comment: Follow the link in your post. You can do `resp.set_cookie('session', '', expires=0)` in `app.after_request` handler.

Comment: @stamaimer I explicitly say I don't want to do this. Additional processing after _every_ request isn't reasonable to me. I'm fishing for configuration that might disable the setting of cookies in general.

Comment: Maybe you can see the 1692 line in the Flask code in app.py. I find flask add `Set-Cookies` in that line.

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom session interface and override `should_set_cookie` method

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSessionInterface, SessionMixin


class CustomSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    def should_set_cookie(self, app: "Flask", session: SessionMixin) -> bool:
        return False


app = Flask(__name__)
app.session_interface = CustomSessionInterface()
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to disable `Set-Cookie` on certain paths, this method gets run on every request and you have access to `request.path`.